# Calling salesforce REST API from sharepoint

Tags: rest-api, rest, authorization

I have a sharepoint app in which I call salesforce REST API.

I have obtained access_token successfully from the app, (using username-password flow)
but when I try to access some resources such as https://instance.salesforce.com/services/data/v30.0/sobjects/Account/ID given the access token inside 'Authorization' header attribute, it responds 401 error saying,
**The remote server returned the following error while establishing a connection - 'Unauthorized'.**

But when I use chrome REST client and do the same request with same access_token it works fine.

Note that sharepoint platform call the REST API on behalf of the client.

Is there any authorized list of hosts that can invoke REST API ?

What am I missing ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not certain if this applies to your situation or not, but I strongly suspect it does. See [Knowledge Article Number: 000214836](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000214836&language=en_US)

> Integration Options for Salesforce files
>
> With the Summer '15 release there are several integration options for Salesforce Files and external systems:
>
> **Files Sync** - this allows bidirection synchronization of files from the desktop of your local machine with Salesforce files
>   For Setup Information see: Install Salesforce Files Sync, Enable Salesforce Files Sync and Grant Users Access to Salesforce Files Sync
>
> - **Secure agent** for on premise Sharepoint 2010 or 2013 ( requires a paid permission set license, “Files Connect for on-premises external data sources.”)
> - **Files Connect** for SharePoint Online or One Drive for Business
> - **Files Connect** for Google Drive.
>
> For Files Connect setup information see: The Files Connect Setup Process

If not, it may be an issue related to not having set up inbound webservices and whitelisted the endpoint.